# passing parameters into a script

Tags: parameters, powershell-3.0

So I've created a function and it works according to the guidelines suggested. However, I have one problem with the script. I  have a function where the parameters are after the function. But I would like to have the parameters be the first thing in the script above the block of code, like in this example:

```
param(statement)
body of script
```

but when I put the parameters above my code nothing happens:

```
Function proper {
    param([switch]$allcaps,[string]$title="")
    if($allcaps) {
        $title.ToUpper()
    } else {
        Foreach($string in $Title) {
            $splitstr=$string.Split(" ")

            $out=@()
            Foreach($word in $splitstr) {

                $out+="{0}{1}" -f $word.Substring(0,1).ToUpper(),$word.substring(1).ToLower()
                if($out -ne 1) {
                    $out = $out -replace 'A','a'
                    $out = $out -replace 'THE','the'
                    $out = $out -replace 'BUT','but'
                    $out = $out -replace 'OR','or'

                    $out = $out -replace 'AT' , 'at'
                    $out = $out -replace 'OF','of'
                    $out = $out -replace'TO','to'
                    $out = $out -replace'WITH','with'
                    $out = $out -replace'IN','in'

                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace 'a','A'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace 'the','The'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace 'but', 'But'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace'or','Or'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace'at','At'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace'of','Of'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace'to','To'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace'with','With'
                    $out[0] = $out[0] -replace'in','In'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal PowerShell scripts have parameters starting with -, like:

```
script.ps1 -server http://devserver
```

Then you handle them in param section in the beginning of the file (see tutorial: http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/01/13/powershell-abcs---p-is-for-parameters.aspx)

You can also assign default values to your params, read them from console if not available or stop script execution:

```
 param (
    [string]$server = "http://defaultserver",
    [string]$username = $(throw "-username is required."),
    [string]$password = $( Read-Host "Input password, please" )
 )
```

Inside the script you can simply

```
write-output $server
```

since all parameters become variables available in script scope.

In this example, the $server gets a default value if the script is called without it, script stops if you omit the -username parameter and asks for terminal input if -password is omitted.

Update: You might as well want to pass a "flag" (a boolean true/false parameter) to a PowerShell script. For instance, your script may accept a "force" where the script runs in a more careful mode when force is not used.

The keyword for that is [switch] parameter type:

```
param (
    [string]$server = "http://defaultserver",
    [string]$password = $( Read-Host "Input password, please" ),
    [switch]$force = $false
 )
```

Inside the script then you would work with it like this:

```
if ($force) {
  //deletes a file or does something "bad"
}
```

Now, when calling the script you'd set the switch/flag parameter like this:

```
.\yourscript.ps1 -server "http://otherserver" -force
```

If you explicitly want to state that the flag is not set, there is a special syntax for that

```
.\yourscript.ps1 -server "http://otherserver" -force:$false
```